# Challenging Java Program Using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Help figuring out this coding question: At this company their are 3 branches and each branch has 3 computers. This network with has a central router that connects the computers to the proper data storage and printers. All print data and storage retrieval data must pass through the router. This router is a single processor. Make a class Router. Then write a stimulation to test your Router code. Create 9 threads one for each port on the Router and launch them simultaneously. Stimulate the functions with the following calls.

Job(PB,1,D,60000)

Job(PB,3,P,100000)

Job(PB,2,D,75000)

Job(FB,1,P,30000)

Job(FB,2,D,150000)

Job(FB,3,P,89000)

Job(MB,1,P,200000)

Job(MB,2,D,140000)

Job(MB,3,P,1350000)

Where Job(Branch, Computer port, D=Data P=Print, Number of characters)

After all runs are done, have your router software print the following by branch:

1. The number of data characters processed and cost of processing.
2. The number of print characters processed and cost of processing.

3 The total of characters processed and total cost of processing.

The charges are computed as follows:

1. Production Branch; print connection 0.007 cents/char, data connection 0.008 cents/char
2. Financial Branch; print connection 0.009 cents/char, data connection 0.007 cent/char
3. Marketing Branch; print connection 0.0095 cents/char, data connection 0.0082

   import java.io.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
    import java.lang.*;
    //import java.lang.Thread;//This allows the threads to be run
    import java.util.concurrent.*;//This allows the creation of a thread pool that can all be launched by 
   //one executor Executor
   import java.util.concurrent.locks.*; //this gives me the ability to lock a function

   ```
   public class Homework_02 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Create PrintWriter for separate output
    PrintWriter outf1;
    outf1=new PrintWriter(new File("Homework_02Out.txt"));

    //create thread pool without executor
    //Production Branch
    Runnable printPB1=new Job("PB",1,'D',60000);
    Runnable printPB3=new Job("PB",3,'P',100000);
    Runnable printPB2=new Job("PB",2,'D',75000);

    //Financial Branch
    Runnable printFB1=new Job("FB",1,'P',30000);
    Runnable printFB2=new Job("FB",2,'D',150000);
    Runnable printFB3=new Job("FB",3,'P',89000);

     //Marketing Branch
     Runnable printMB1=new Job("MB",1,'P',200000);
     Runnable printMB2=new Job("MB",2,'D',140000);
   Runnable printMB3=new Job("MB",3,'P',135000);

   //Create Threads
   Thread thread1=new Thread(printPB1);
   Thread thread2=new Thread(printPB2);
   Thread thread3=new Thread(printPB3);
   Thread thread4=new Thread(printFB1);
   Thread thread5=new Thread(printFB2);
   Thread thread6=new Thread(printFB3);
   Thread thread7=new Thread(printMB1);
   Thread thread8=new Thread(printMB2);
   Thread thread9=new Thread(printMB3);

   /*Prioritize (if needed)
   thread1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread3.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread4.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread5.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread6.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread7.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread8.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   thread9.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
   */

   //Now start the threads
   thread1.start();
   thread2.start();
   thread3.start();
   thread4.start();
   thread5.start();
   thread6.start();
   thread7.start();
   thread8.start();
   thread9.start();

   //flush(if needed)
   outf1.flush();
   }


   }

   class Job implements Runnable{
   private String branch;
   private int port;
   private static char type;
   private static double characters;

   public Job(String b, int x, char t, double num){
   branch=b;
   port=x;
   type=t;
   characters=num;
   }

   public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is not directly related to multithreading, but to distributed programming because you have many computers, not many threads on the same computer. I suggest to change the title.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I am lazy when it comes to completing other people's homework

Comment: That's as far as i have got.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO, the OP is asking for help writing a multithreaded program that _simulates_ what you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not quite what was asked for as I don't see the need for threads but I've used threads anyway. I've also used `Lock`s to demonstrate how they work, but I have also used `Atomic`s so the locks are probably not necessary.

```
enum Branch {

    Production(0.007, 0.008),
    Financial(0.009, 0.007),
    Marketing(0.0095, 0.0082);
    // PB/FB/MB
    final String id = name().charAt(0) + "B";
    // Costs.
    final double printCost;
    final double dataCost;

    private Branch(double printCost, double dataCost) {
        this.printCost = printCost;
        this.dataCost = dataCost;
    }

    // One lock for each computer at this branch.
    Lock[] computers = new Lock[3];

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < computers.length; i++) {
            computers[i] = new ReentrantLock();
        }
    }

    public void lock(int computer) {
        computers[computer - 1].lock();
    }

    public void unlock(int computer) {
        computers[computer - 1].unlock();
    }

    AtomicInteger dataProcessed = new AtomicInteger();

    public void data(int amount) {
        dataProcessed.addAndGet(amount);
    }

    AtomicInteger printProcessed = new AtomicInteger();

    public void print(int amount) {
        printProcessed.addAndGet(amount);
    }

    public static Branch lookup(String id) {
        for (Branch b : Branch.values()) {
            if (b.id.equals(id)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void printStats() {
        System.out.println("Branch " + name()
                + " processed " + dataProcessed
                + " cost=" + (dataProcessed.get() * dataCost)
                + " printed " + printProcessed
                + " cost=" + (printProcessed.get() * printCost)
        );
    }

}

enum Function {

    Data {

                @Override
                void function(Branch b, int size) {
                    b.data(size);
                }
            },
    Print {
                @Override
                void function(Branch b, int size) {
                    b.print(size);
                }
            };
    // D/P
    final String id = "" + name().charAt(0);

    public static Function lookup(String id) {
        for (Function b : Function.values()) {
            if (b.id.equals(id)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    abstract void function(Branch b, int size);
}

class Router {

    public void job(String branch, int computer, String function, int size) {
        Branch b = Branch.lookup(branch);
        // Grab the lock on that computer at that branch.
        b.lock(computer);
        try {
            Function f = Function.lookup(function);
            f.function(b, size);
        } finally {
            b.unlock(computer);
        }
    }

    private void job(Job j) {
        job(j.branch, j.computer, j.function, j.data);
    }

    private void printStats() {
        // For all branches:
        for (Branch b : Branch.values()) {
            b.printStats();
        }
    }
}
// Just one router.
final Router router = new Router();

class Job implements Runnable {

    String branch;
    int computer;
    String function;
    int data;

    public Job(String branch, int computer, String function, int data) {
        this.branch = branch;
        this.computer = computer;
        this.function = function;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        router.job(this);
    }

}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    Job[] jobs = {
        new Job("PB", 1, "D", 60000),
        new Job("PB", 3, "P", 100000),
        new Job("PB", 2, "D", 75000),
        new Job("FB", 1, "P", 30000),
        new Job("FB", 2, "D", 150000),
        new Job("FB", 3, "P", 89000),
        new Job("MB", 1, "P", 200000),
        new Job("MB", 2, "D", 140000),
        new Job("MB", 3, "P", 1350000)};
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[jobs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(jobs[i]);
        threads[i].start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    router.printStats();
}
```

prints:

```
Branch Production processed 135000 cost=1080.0 printed 100000 cost=700.0
Branch Financial processed 150000 cost=1050.0 printed 119000 cost=1071.0
Branch Marketing processed 140000 cost=1148.0 printed 1550000 cost=14725.0
```

Please note carefully - as a professional developer I post professional level code. Please do not attempt to present this to your teacher as if it was yours. They will know immediately that it is not.

You should use this code to understand the techniques that are available to you.

Comment: where did the .values() and name(). start?

Comment: @m1arvin23 - [values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html#values--) is a method you can use on an `enum` class that gives you an array of all entries. [name()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) gives you a string representation of the name of the enum - e.g. `Branch.Production.name()` would return the string `"Production"`.

Comment: So what if i wanted to create classes instead of using enum? Is there an equivalent way of doing that with making regular classes?

Comment: @m1arvin23 - then you must learn the way padawan.